# how do I group this in array

Tags: php

```
$db_string = "|1||3||1||5||1||3||8||1||10||2|2||13||2||15|";
$array = array_filter(explode("|", $db_string)); 

 if(in_array("1", $array)){
  echo"<li>
         <a href="#">Honeymoon Packages</a>
       </li>";
  }

RESULT is Coming

* Honeymoon Packages
* Honeymoon Packages
* Honeymoon Packages
* Honeymoon Packages
```

*because in array 1 is there 4 times, how do I group this in array and print result one time without duplicate?*

Comment: Cf. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do prefer splitting with a regex, so no empty values will ever occur.

```php
$db_string = "|1||3||1||5||1||3||8||1||10||2|2||13||2||15|";
$array =  preg_split('/\|/', $db_string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Now the array has an element for each number in the listed order. With the help of array map we use the empty `$data` array and build a key for unique element. So we know how many entries are there per item.

```php
$data = [];
array_map(function($e) use (&$data) { isset($data[$e]) ? $data[$e]++ : $data[$e] = 1; }, $array);
```

```
Array
(
    [1] => 4
    [3] => 2
    [5] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [10] => 1
    [2] => 3
    [13] => 1
    [15] => 1
)
```

You can use the keys to have each item uniquely.

```php
print_r(array_unique(array_keys($data)));
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 13
    [7] => 15
)
```

Comment: $db_string = "|1||3||1||5||1||3||8||1||10||2|2||13||2||15|";

like this multiple rows have in th database from all the rows i need to duplicate multiple number and group

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. You can see the grouping in the first print_r() of my answer. Key one occurs 4 times, key 3 occurs twice, and so on. That's what's called grouping in database manner.

Comment: Actually, this is one of my website menus, under the menu, there is a tab PACKAGE.
Packages added to the website under multiple categories like (HONEYMOON, FAMILY, SPA, LUXURY) so each package can select multiple categories, so every package category field saved in the database like (HONEYMOON||FAMILY||SPA||PACKAGE|).

so when I print using array in the menu categories coming multiple times, that is why I want to group. hope understand my requirement

Comment: Sadly I can not follow your description. Usually menus are organized with parents and children and are displayed with a simple recursion.